# How to add condition based on the size we input?

Tags: c++, algorithm

How to add condition based on the size we input?
we have height and width of a image.
and I need to know the pixel in that position belongs to which cluster .
e.g the pixel inside the rect

```
01
34

45
78  etc
```

For 2x2.  we have 田 like this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

for 3x3, we have 9 rectangles:

```
0 1 2  3
4 5 6  7
8 9 10 11
```

for 4x4, we have 16 rectangles and so on:

```
0  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

For 2x2, I need four conditions like (<= and >) inside < and (<= and >) inside <.

```
for (int current_row = 0; current_row < height; current_row += sample_rate) {
    for (int current_col = 0; current_col < width; current_col += sample_rate) {
        if (current_col <= (width / 2)) {
            if (current_row <= (height / 2)) {
            }
            else if (current_row > (height / 2)) {
            }
        }

        else if (current_col > (width / 2)) {
            if (current_row <= (height / 2)) {
            }
            else if (current_row > (height / 2)) {
            }
        }
    }
```

```
for (int current_row = 0; current_row < height; current_row += sample_rate) {
    for (int current_col = 0; current_col < width; current_col += sample_rate) {
     if (current_col <= (width / 3)) {

                    if (current_row < (height / 3)) {
                       

                    } else if ((current_row >= (height / 3)) && (current_row <= (height / 3 * 2))) {

                    } else if (current_row > (height / 3 * 2)) {
                        
                    }

                    

                } else if (current_col > (width / 3) && current_col < (width / 3 * 2)) {

                    if (current_row < (height / 3)) {


                    } else if ((current_row >= (height / 3)) && (current_row <= (height / 3 * 2))) {

                    } else if (current_row > (height / 3 * 2)) {

                    }

          

                } else if (current_col > (width / 3 * 2)) {
                    if (current_row < (height / 3)) {

                    } else if ((current_row >= (height / 3)) && (current_row <= (height / 3 * 2))) {

                    } else if (current_row > (height / 3 * 2)) {

                    }
   
  }
}
```

and for  4x4 or more, beside <= and >, I need more condition like the range condition like >sth && < sth.

How can I use one function to support all of them?

Sorry for my English, and any terminology for this kind of problem? (I don't know how to describe my problem using keyword for me to search, so I decide to post here)

Comment: @JeJo I have add 3x3 condition , thx for your help.

Comment: For 3x3, shouldn't you have the values from 0 to 15? (You mention from 0 to 11)

Comment: @Dominique you are right, I will handle that after set up the condition.  the value 0-15 is for me to fit some ratio into correct position for another matrix